# Disablling cache in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, caching

I am having a weird bug that seems related to Djangos caching.

I have a 3-step registration process:

1. insert personal data
2. insert company data
3. summary view and submit all data for registration

If person A walks through the process to the summary part but does not submit the form and
person B does the same, person B gets the data of person A in the summary view.

The data gets stored in a `Storage` object which carries the data through each step. Every new registration instanciates a new `Storage` object (at least it should).

While debugging I've found that Django does not call any method in the corresponding views when the cache is already warmed up (by another running registration) and I guess that's why there is no new `Storage` instance. Hence the cross-polution of data.

Now I'm perfectly aware that I can decorate the method with `@never_cache()` (which it already was) but that doesn't do the trick.

I've also found that the `@never_cache` decorator does not work properly prior to Django 1.9(?) as it misses some headers.

One solution that I've found was to set these headers myself with `@cache_control(max_age=0, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)`. But that also doesn't work.

So how can I properly disable caching for these methods?

Here is some relevant code:

```py
# views.py

def _request_storage(request, **kwargs):
    try:
        return getattr(request, '_registration_storage')
    except AttributeError:
        from .storage import Storage
        storage = Storage(request, 'registration')
        setattr(request, '_registration_storage', storage)
        return storage

...

# Route that gets called by clicking the "register" button
@secure_required
@cache_control(max_age=0, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)
# also does not work with @never_cache()
def registration_start(request, **kwargs):
    storage = _request_storage(request)
    storage.clear()
    storage.store_data('is_authenticated', request.user.is_authenticated())
    storage.store_data('user_pk', request.user.pk if request.user.is_authenticated() else None)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_i18n('registration_package', kwargs={'pk': 6}))

def registration_package(request, pk=None, **kwargs):
    """stores the package_pk in storage"""
    ...

def registration_personal(request, pk=None, **kwargs):
    from .forms import PersonalForm
    storage = _request_storage(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonalForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            storage.store_form('personal_form_data', form)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_i18n('registration_company'))
    else:
        if request.GET.get('revalidate', False):
            form = storage.retrieve_form('personal_form_data', PersonalForm)
        else:
            form = storage.retrieve_initial_form('personal_form_data', PersonalForm)
    return render_to_response('registration/personal.html', {
        'form': form,
        'step': 'personal',
        'previous': _previous_steps(request),
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

# the other steps are pretty much the same
```

```py
# storage.py

class Storage(object):
    def __init__(self, request, prefix):
        self.request = request
        self.prefix = prefix

    def _debug(self):
        from pprint import pprint
        self._init_storage()
        pprint(self.request.session[self.prefix])

    def exists(self):
        return self.prefix in self.request.session

    def has(self, key):
        if self.prefix in self.request.session:
            return key in self.request.session[self.prefix]
        return False

    def _init_storage(self,):
        if not self.prefix in self.request.session:
            self.request.session[self.prefix] = {}
            self.request.session.modified = True

    def clear(self):
        self.request.session[self.prefix] = {}
        self.request.session.modified = True

    def store_data(self, key, data):
        self._init_storage()
        self.request.session[self.prefix][key] = data
        self.request.session.modified = True

    def update_data(self, key, data):
        self._init_storage()
        if key in self.request.session[self.prefix]:
            self.request.session[self.prefix][key].update(data)
            self.request.session.modified = True
        else:
            self.store_data(key, data)

    def retrieve_data(self, key, fallback=None):
        self._init_storage()
        return self.request.session[self.prefix].get(key, fallback)

    def store_form(self, key, form):
        self.store_data(key, form.data)

    def retrieve_form_data(self, key):
        return self.retrieve_data(key)

    def retrieve_form(self, key, form_class):
        data = self.retrieve_form_data(key)
        form = form_class(data=data)
        return form

    def retrieve_initial_form(self, key, form_class):
        data = self.retrieve_form_data(key)
        form = form_class(initial=self.convert_form_data_to_initial(data))
        return form

    def convert_form_data_to_initial(self, data):
        result = {}
        if data is None:
            return result
        for key in data:
            try:
                values = data.getlist(key)
                if len(values) > 1:
                    result[key] = values
                else:
                    result[key] = data.get(key)
            except AttributeError:
                result[key] = data.get(key)
        return result

    def retrieve_process_form(self, key, form_class, initial=None):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return form_class(data=request.POST)
        else:
            data = self.get_form_data(key)
            initial = self.convert_form_data_to_initial(data) or initial
            return form_class(initial=initial)
```

I've tested this across browser, computers and networks. When I clear the cache manually it works again.

(Easy to see with just debugging `print()` statements which do not get called with a warm cache.)

It can't be too hard to selectively disable caching, right?

**Additional question:**
Could it be that the `@never_cache()` decorator just prevents browser-caching and has nothing to do with the Redis cache?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're avoiding use of sessions?

Comment: @2ps it is a legacy application I've inherited from another dev team. I am just trying to patch things up until we do a rewrite. There is a lot of things wrong with the app but I'm not trying to sink too much time into it. So no, I have not seen a reason why they didn't use sessions.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with caching; most likely, something here is breaking thread safety (although I can't spot it at the moment). Can you explain exactly what you are doing to "clear the cache manually"?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sure. I'm clearing the Redis cache via a management command.